# How do I make Google search with multiple sets of filter conditions?

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to combine two search queries consisted of multiple search operators into one search query, but it's not working.

1st query:

```
trade war site:bbc.com AND inurl:world-43512098
```

2nd query:

```
trade war site:cnn.com AND inurl:2019/07/19/economy
```

Combined query:

```
trade war (site:bbc.com AND inurl:world-43512098) OR (site:cnn.com AND inurl:2019/07/19/economy)
```

---

[image: search result demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1st query:
>
> trade war site:bbc.com AND inurl:world-43512098
>
> 2nd query:
>
> trade war site:cnn.com AND inurl:2019/07/19/economy
>
> Combined query:
>
> <s>trade war (site:bbc.com AND inurl:world-43512098) OR (site:cnn.com AND inurl:2019/07/19/economy)</s>

Google [Advanced Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) Help - no parentheses

Combined query

`trade war site:bbc.com OR site:cnn.com AND inurl:world-43512098 OR inurl:2019/07/19/economy`

Explanation: (search terms) AND (Site #1) OR (Site #2) + (URL #1) OR (URL #2)

[Proof it works](https://www.google.com/search?ei=koA2Xe2AN8fe0gLC5pnICQ&q=trade%20war%20site%3Abbc.com%20OR%20site%3Acnn.com%20AND%20inurl%3Aworld-43512098%20OR%20inurl%3A2019%2F07%2F19%2Feconomy&oq=trade%20war%20site%3Abbc.com%20OR%20site%3Acnn.com%20AND%20inurl%3Aworld-43512098%20OR%20inurl%3A2019%2F07%2F19%2Feconomy):

[image: Search Result]

Trying:

- trade war site:bbc.com AND inurl:world-43512098 OR site:cnn.com AND inurl:2019/07/19/economy
- trade war site:bbc.com inurl:world-43512098 OR site:cnn.com inurl:2019/07/19/economy
- trade war (site:bbc.com AND inurl:world-43512098) OR (site:cnn.com AND inurl:2019/07/19/economy) - which you used

doesn't work.